# error instatlling ruby on rails in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I was trying to install **ruby** on rails in **mac**. 
I have **Xcode and gcc compiler** installed. When i tried to install **git**, it showed me the following error:

```
$:~ gem install git
$ ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/git-1.2.5
```

I changed the permissions of my **1.8 and gems directory**. Still it is showing the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `sudo`?  Try `sudo gem install git`.

Reference documentation: https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git#install